# Join using dynamic column names SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which can output any number of different columns (from 'Level1' to 'Level'N).

I need to perform a left join on each of these dynamic columns against a CTE

I have written the following script but keep getting this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15 Incorrect syntax near '10'.

To troubleshoot, I have tried removing the each of the variables in the CTE with no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
DECLARE @rel varchar(4) = CAST('X112' AS varchar(4))
DECLARE @todaysdate date = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())

--create cte

DECLARE @sqltext varchar(MAX) =



' WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT
                 ID 
            ,STARTDATE 
            ,ENDDATE 
            ,NEWID             

FROM Tbl

WHERE TYPE = ''' + @rel + '''
AND ENDDATE >= ' + CAST(@todaysdate AS varchar(30)) +' AND STARTDATE <= ' + CAST(@todaysdate AS varchar(30)) +'
)

SELECT ID, NEWID, Level';

--find max lvl, convert to str

DECLARE @counter int = (SELECT MAX(lvl) FROM tbl2)
DECLARE @counterstring varchar(3)

SET @counterstring = CAST(@counter AS varchar(3))

WHILE @counter != 0 

BEGIN

        SET @sqltext = @sqltext + @counterstring + ' INTO tbl3 '

                             + ' FROM tbl2 a '
                             + ' LEFT JOIN CTE c ON a.Level' + @counterstring + ' = c.NEWID'

        SET @counter = @counter - 1


END

EXEC(@sqltext)
```

```
--edited version
DECLARE @rel varchar(4) = CAST('X112' AS varchar(4))
DECLARE @todaysdate date = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())

DECLARE @sqltext varchar(MAX) =

' WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT
                 ID
            ,STARTDATE 
            ,ENDDATE AS mgmt_ENDDA
            ,NEWID

FROM tbl 

WHERE SUBTY = ''' + @rel + '''
AND ENDDATE >= ' + CAST(@todaysdate AS varchar(30)) +' AND STARTDATE <= ' + CAST(@todaysdate AS varchar(30)) +'
)

INSERT INTO tbl3

SELECT ID, NEWID, Level';

DECLARE @counter int = (SELECT MAX(lvl) FROM tbl2)
DECLARE @counterstring varchar(3)


WHILE @counter != 0 

BEGIN

        SET @counterstring = CAST(@counter AS varchar(3))

        SET @sqltext = @sqltext + @counterstring 
                                + ' FROM tbl2 a '
                                + ' LEFT JOIN CTE c ON a.Level' + @counterstring + ' = c.NEWID'
        SET @counter = @counter - 1


END

EXEC(@sqltext)
```

Comment: Your `SELECT` is missing a `FROM` clause. Should probably be `WITH CTE AS (...) SELECT ID, NEWID, Level FROM CTE`

Comment: Thanks for this. I am concatenating the `SELECT ID, NEWID, Level'` with the `@counterstring` variable below - so in `SET @sqltext = @sqltext + @counterstring + ' INTO tbl3 '  `. This is followed by `+ ' FROM tbl2 a '`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `select * into` query creates a new table each time, I am assuming that you are trying to create 'n' number of tables for 'n' number of levels, with the result obtained by joining with nth column. I have 2 suggestions for you

1. Bring the select query within the while loop and append ';' at the end of the loop to split select queries.
2. instead of `INTO tbl3` use `INTO tbl + @counterstring` as select * into will create new table

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately I am trying to add the `ID, NEWID, Level(n)` columns to a single table

Comment: Then, I think you should write insert into and then write the select statement and that should fix your issue.

Comment: Then, the order of query should be  with cte as( ).. insert into tbl3..select from tbl2 a <dynamic join part> . So, write insert into on top of select , remove into tbl3, place from tbl2 a outside loop as that is going to be static

Comment: That makes sense. I've moved the `insert` line to above `SELECT ID, NEWID, Level'`. Unfortunately its still coming up with the same error on line 17 which is `AND ENDDATE >= ' + CAST(@todaysdate AS varchar(30)) +' AND STARTDATE <= ' + CAST(@todaysdate AS varchar(30)) +` so removed it but the error moved to the line above. I'm looking at the CTE atm, think the error is there

Comment: Print the query string, so that you can debug it easily

Comment: The issue is in the left join, for some reason NEWID has the @counter variable appended to it. It works fine if I take it out of the while loop, but doesn't work if I put it back in.

Comment: can you put your reworked while loop here? I suspect the first line of your while loop but I can be sure if i see it once

Comment: I have added to the original post

Answer (score 0):

Can you change it like this and try again?

```
--edited version
DECLARE @rel varchar(4) = CAST('A012' AS varchar(4))
DECLARE @todaysdate date = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())

DECLARE @sqltext varchar(MAX) =

' WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT
                 ID
            ,STARTDATE 
            ,ENDDATE AS mgmt_ENDDA
            ,NEWID

FROM tbl 

WHERE SUBTY = ''' + @rel + '''
AND ENDDATE >= ' + CAST(@todaysdate AS varchar(30)) +' AND STARTDATE <= ' + CAST(@todaysdate AS varchar(30)) +'
)

INSERT INTO tbl3';

DECLARE @counter int = (SELECT MAX(lvl) FROM tbl2)
DECLARE @counterstring varchar(3)


WHILE @counter != 0 

BEGIN

        SET @counterstring = CAST(@counter AS varchar(3))

        SET @sqltext = @sqltext + CHAR(10) +'SELECT ID, NEWID, Level'+@counterstring

        SET @sqltext = @sqltext + ' FROM tbl2 a '
                                + ' LEFT JOIN CTE c ON a.Level' + @counterstring + ' = c.NEWID'

        SET @counter = @counter - 1

        IF @counter <> 0
            SET @sqltext = @sqltext + CHAR(10) + ' UNION '


END

EXEC(@sqltext)
```

You can try 'UNION ALL' instead of 'UNION' if you dont want to get rid of duplicate data. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your continued help. Unfortunately it is still throwing up an error `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition`

Comment: Can you post the table structure of tbl3 and the resultant dynamic query, because the error ses very much straightforward. There should be some mismatch between structure of tbl3 and the selected values. If you are not aware, do print(sqltext) to get the dynamic query result.

Comment: Try insert into tbl3(column_name1, column_name2,column_name3) instead of insert into tbl3